# How to compare a varchar column to time part of a date in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I have a column(varchar) named "StartTime" that save the time part of a date for example "9:30".  I need to get all the games that started between one hour before and hour after a given start time.

I cannot change the column datatype because it belongs to a legacy system.

```
Game.findAll({
            where: {
                status: "finished",               
                $and: [
                      { startTime: { $lt: /*onehourafter*/} },
                      { startTime: { $gt: /*onehourbefore*/} }
                ]
            }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you can accomplish this using the TIMESTAMPDIFF function (other DBs likely have something similar).  Below is an example that will return 1 hour:

```
abs(timestampdiff(hour,'2019-01-10 16:30','2019-01-10 17:30'))
```

This assumes you can transform your target start time and the database string field into  date/time strings.  There are a couple of permutations to consider - such as midnight yesterday is within an hour of 1:00 AM today.  Here are some examples:

```
abs(timestampdiff(hour,'2019-01-10 00:30','2019-01-09 21:30')) day_earlier,
abs(timestampdiff(hour,'2019-01-10 00:30','2019-01-11 01:30')) day_later
```

You might consider writing a database function to encapsulate the logic - otherwise your sequelizer query is going to be pretty complicated...